# Rails 2.3.x - How to stub a helper method (that gets called from a view) in a functional test (no RSpec)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, functional-testing, helper, mocha.js

Please don't tell me "search more" or other stuff cause all solutions for similar question fail.

Simple:
I have a functional tests. I want to make a simple get and see if proper content gets rendered

```
  test "displays headline if user should see it" do
    get :index  
    assert_match /headline/, response.body
  end

  test "doesn't display headline if user shouldn't see it" do
    get :index
    assert_no_match /headline/, response.body
  end
```

and a simple view

```
  <% if show_headline?(arg) %>
    headline
  <% end %>
```

and a helper:

```
  module TheHelper
    def show_headline?(arg)
      arg ? hard_code_logic : even_harder_logic
    end
  end
```

so what I need is to do in test something like:

```
  test "displays headline if user should see it" do
    Something.stubs(:show_headline?).returns(true)

    get :index  
    assert_match /headline/, response.body
  end

  test "doesn't display headline if user shouldn't see it" do
    Something.stubs(:show_headline?).returns(false)

    get :index
    assert_no_match /headline/, response.body
  end
```

The question is what is Something? I want to stub it cause I have helpers tested in unit/helpers.

After the get helper module gets remixed into the controller class. Please don't give me links to other answers, I read them (but of course I could have read the wrong ones) and they don't work for me. I use Rails 2.3.10 with mocha 0.9.8.

Things that don't work:

```
TheController.any_instance.stubs(:show_headline?)
ActionView::Base.any_instance...
@controller.stubs...
```

UPDATE:

the only mock that worked was:

```
  <% self.stubs(:show_headline?).returns(true) >%
  <% if show_headline?(arg) %>
    headline
  <% end %>
```

but of course I will not use that... maybe it is a clue